# Microsoft Edge failed to restore tabs of the previous session

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I was low on memory so I thought it would be a good idea to restart Edge so the memory of most tabs would be released. When I opened it again, I clicked the "Restore" button, but nothing happened.

Sending "Ctrl+Shift+T" didn't help, restarting Edge didn't help, and (maybe because of the order) the tabs weren't in "Recently closed". I have looked around some of the cache files of Appdata/Local/Microsoft/Edge but the ones I've opened looked like noise (opened them in Notepad++).
Is there anything to do here apart from combing the entire browsing history?

Comment: Unfortunately your last browser session is permanently lost. As for the reason it was probably due to the low amount of memory available. Edge by default will suspend tabs automatically when they are not active for awhile. So the browser restart wasn’t necessary to free memory from inactive tabs

Comment: I had that setting disabled, is it possible that the information is somewhere? It freed about 10 GB.

Comment: Your browser session when Edge closed was not saved properly so it cannot be recovered.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything to do here apart from combing the entire browsing history?

Unfortunately, the browser session you had opened wasn’t properly saved, likely being connected to your low memory state. The inconsistency of Chromium based browsers not saved the last session can be resolved be extensions that saved your session explicitly.

Edge by default will suspend tabs automatically when they are not active for awhile. So the browser restart wasn’t necessary to free memory from inactive tabs any memory that was made available was being actively used by Edge.